# How do I achieve this CSS effect on the Image?

Tags: css, styled-components

I am using the style component library and am trying to blur the sides of an image like in the following example:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea on how to do this? This is the code that I have for the component that I am trying to achieve this on:

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const StyledTopicItem = styled.div`
  position:relative;
  height: 2.5rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  height:20vh;
  justify-content:center
`;


const Topic = styled.div`
position:absolute;
bottom:1px;
font-weight:bold;
`


interface topicItemProps {
  topic: string;
  setSelectedTopic: (value: string) => void;
}

export const TopicItem = ({ topic, setSelectedTopic }: topicItemProps) => {
  return (
    <StyledTopicItem
      onClick={(e: any) => {
        setSelectedTopic(e.target?.innerText);
      }}
    >
      <img  alt={""} src={'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1514921674539-8b1710289b0d?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwzNDE2fDB8MXxyYW5kb218fHx8fHx8fHwxNjQyNjg0OTgz&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85'} height={150} width={250}/> <br/>
    <Topic>{topic}</Topic>
    </StyledTopicItem>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `object-fit`, `background` and `backdrop-filter` . eventually `aspect-ratio` can help even your boxes if you have more than one and CSS `var()` to simplify your CSS.

example

```css
img {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  object-fit:contain;
  backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
}
div{
  
  background:var(--bg) center center / cover  transparent;
   aspect-ratio: 3 / 2;
  border:solid;
  height:200px;
}
body {
display:flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
gap:1em;
}
```

```html
<div class style="--bg:url(https://picsum.photos/id/59/200/200)" >
<img src=https://picsum.photos/id/59/200/200 >
</div>

<div class style="--bg:url(https://picsum.photos/id/58/200/200)" >
<img src=https://picsum.photos/id/58/200/200 >
</div>

<div class style="--bg:url(https://picsum.photos/id/57/200/200)" >
<img src=https://picsum.photos/id/57/200/200 >
</div>
```